# Check if string is a valid JSON with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I need to catch an error when lifting a service. The response can be `null`, a string error message like

`error services-migration/foobar: Not found: services-migration/foobar`

or a valid JSON when everything is fine. I was wondering if there is a way with `jq` to simply check if the provided string is a valid JSON. I could ofc check the string for some keywords like `error` f.e., but I'm looking for a more robust option, where eg. I get a `true/false` or `1/0` from jq.
I was looking through the docs of `jq` and also some questions here on SO but everything was about finding and picking out key-values from a JSON, but nothing about simply validating a string.

UPDATE:

I've got this:

```
 result=$(some command)
```

from which the result is the string `error services-migration/foobar: Not found: services-migration/foobar`

And then the if statement:

```
 if jq -e . >/dev/null 2>&1 <<<"$result"; then
    echo "it catches it"
 else
    echo "it doesn't catch it"
 fi
```

And it always ends up in the `else` clause.

Comment: Does jq not exit with an error if the json is invalid?

Comment: Yeah, it gives a `parse error`, but I was wondering if there's a way to get simply `1` or `0` or `true/false`

Comment: You get that in the return code, just send stderr from the command to `/dev/null`

Comment: Are you just checking if the response is json, then running other commands? Or are you checking, then want to run filters on it? There are ways you could do that in pure jq, but it'll depend on what you want to do with after you check if it's json or not.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From the manual:

> -e / --exit-status:
>
> Sets  the  exit  status of jq to 0 if the last output values was neither false nor null, 1 if the last output value was either false or null, or 4 if no valid result was ever produced. Normally jq exits with 2 if there was any usage problem or system error, 3 if there was a jq program compile error, or 0 if the jq program ran.

So you can use:

```
if jq -e . >/dev/null 2>&1 <<<"$json_string"; then
    echo "Parsed JSON successfully and got something other than false/null"
else
    echo "Failed to parse JSON, or got false/null"
fi
```

In fact, if you don't care about distinguishing between the different types of error, then you can just lose the `-e` switch. In this case, anything considered to be valid JSON (including false/null) will be parsed successfully by the filter `.` and the program will terminate successfully, so the `if` branch will be followed.

Comment: Oooh, sorry, my bad. I need the `else` branch because I am actually going to encapsulate this rule in a `while` loop. So I need to proceed with the `while` if it fails to parse the JSON. What would be the negation of that `jq` command?

Comment: You can negate it using an exclamation mark: `while ! jq . >/dev/null 2>&1 <<<"$result"`, or use `until` instead of `while`.

Comment: This does not work for `json_string='{"omg":"lol"'`. According to https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1539 you should use `jq type` and see if the result is empty.

Comment: @Konrad thanks for sharing the link, but on my version of jq (1.5), that input leads to an empty output with both `jq .` and `jq type`.

Comment: I don't know if `jq .` has any edge cases, so I'd personally go for `jq type`. Both return with exit code `0` which is what you are testing in your snippet.

So for `json_string='{"omg":"lol"'` your snippet returns `Parsed JSON successfully and got something other than false/null`.

 (I see that my comment may not have been clear enough: by "result" I mean "output".)

Comment: Oh, `jq type` is what I needed. I've been searching for a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

This is working for me

```
echo $json_string | jq -e . >/dev/null 2>&1  | echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]}
```

that returns return code:

- 0 - Success
- 1 - Failed
- 4 - Invalid

Then you can evaluate the return code by further code.

Comment: You can consolidate this a bit, if you prefer:  `./jq -e . >/dev/null 2>&1 <<< "${json_string}"`

Comment: I am not really sure here. The first run can give you either an empty result, then rerun the same command gives you a 0.

Comment: the PIPESTATUS will give you previous command pipe status not working on the current line of command.

Comment: not ```| echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]}```, use ```; echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]}```

Answer (score 7):

The commands and explanations below attempt to use `jq` in the least expensive way, just as means to validate JSON. In my opinion, there are tools better suited for this (Like JSONLint), but if the only thing you have at hand is `jq` then this is my contribution.

To validate a JSON file and still get the errors in `STDERR` output using `jq` you can use the following bash one-liner

```sh
jq -reM '""' <<<'<MAYBE_INVALID_JSON>' 1>/dev/null
```

Which reads as:

- Execute `jq` with flags:

  - `-r` to output a raw value (No processing or formatting)
  - `-e` to exit with a code greater than `0` if there was an error
  - `-M` do not colorize JSON
- The first `jq` argument is `'""'` which outputs an empty string, effectively preventing `jq` from making any processing of the JSON for printing
- `<<<` followed by a string is called a "Here String", and is basically telling bash to treat the string as if it was a file and pass it to `STDIN` (As input to the command).

  Note that you can replace `<<<'<MAYBE_INVALID_JSON>'` with the path of a file you want to validate and it would still work
- Then redirect any `STDOUT` output (Which normally will contain the JSON) to `/dev/null`, effectively discarding it

You can also get fancier and output a custom message below the errors by using the following:

```sh
jq -reM '""' <<<'<MAYBE_INVALID_JSON>' 1>/dev/null || ( exit_code="$?"; echo 'ERROR: Invalid JSON file. See errors above' 1>&2; exit "$exit_code" )
```

Where the added portion reads as follows:

- `||` means: If the previous command failed with a non-zero exit code then run the following command
- Open a sub-shell with `(`. This is actually needed since we want to exit with the original command's exit code

  - Set the `exit_code` environment variable to the exit code of the last command `$?`
  - Print custom error message using `echo`
  - `exit` the sub-shell with the exit code from the original command `$exit_code`
- Close the sub-shell

Comment: Nice, thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

For a **variable** content like for a line, that's been working for me

```
echo "$my_potential_json"|jq empty > /dev/null 2>&1                                                                                                                                                
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "found valid json:$my_potential_json"
    do_whatever....
```