# How can I prettyprint JSON on the command line, but allow invalid JSON objects to pass though?

Tags: json, bash, logging, command-line, pipe

I'm currently tailing some logs in bash that are half JSON, half text like below:

```
{"response":{"message":"asdfasdf"}}

{"log":{"example":"asdfasdf"}}

here is some text

{"another":{"example":"asdfasdf"}}

more text
```

Each line is either a full valid JSON object or some text that would fail a JSON parser.

I've looked at `jq` and `underscore-cli` to see if they have options to return the invalid object in the case of failure, but I'm not seeing any.

I've also tried to use a `||` operator to cat the piped input, but I'm losing the value somehow. Maybe I should read up on pipes more? Example: `getLogs -t | (underscore print || cat)`

I think I could write a script that stores the input. Format it, and return the output if successful. If it fails returned the stored value. I feel like there should be a simpler way though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I don't have an answer to your question, but wanted to quickly note that you can format text as code block by fencing it with three backticks (```). Inline code can be marked with single backticks (`code`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this node library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify)

install with

```
$ npm install -g js-beautify
```

Here is what I did:

```
$ js-beautify -r test.js
beautified test.js
```

I tested it with an incomplete json file and it worked

Answer (score 2):

[jq](/questions/tagged/jq) can [check for invalid json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954692/check-if-string-is-a-valid-json-with-jq)

```
#!/bin/bash
while read p; do
    if jq -e . >/dev/null 2>&1 <<<"$p"; then
        echo $p | jq
    else
        echo 'Skipping invalid json'
    fi
done < /tmp/tst.txt
```

```
{
  "response": {
    "message": "asdfasdf"
  }
}
{
  "log": {
    "example": "asdfasdf"
  }
}
Skipping invalid json
{
  "another": {
    "example": "asdfasdf"
  }
}
Skipping invalid json
```