# Pipe output through jq ONLY if it is JSON

Tags: bash, curl, conditional-statements, jq

I have the following BASH code:

```
    response=$( curl -Ls $endpoint )
    if [ -n "$response" ]; then  # nonempty
        echo "$response"  | jq .
    fi
```

The problem is that sometimes the response can be non-empty but not JSON (if it's not a 200).

Is it possible to pipe the output through `jq` ONLY if it is valid JSON?

The following works:

```
echo $x | jq . 2>/dev/null  || echo $x
```

Test:

```
> x='{"foo":123}'; echo $x | jq . 2>/dev/null || echo "Invalid: $x"
{
  "foo": 123
}

> x='}'; echo $x | jq . 2>/dev/null || echo "Invalid: $x"
Invalid: }
```

However, I don't feel comfortable with it.

Comment: Note that `echo` won't always work, depending on the implementation. Some implementations process backslash escapes. `printf '%s' "$x"` is more reliable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to test the response type before submitting it to `jq`, it is possible if you test the `Content-Type` header from the server's response.

So you want `curl` to send you the full response headers and body with `curl -i`.

Here is an implementation of it:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

endpoint='https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Paris.json'

# Headers and body are delimited by an empty line, with CRLF as the line ending.
# See: RFC7230 HTTP/1.1 Message Syntax and Routing / section 3: Message Format
# https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3
crlf="$(printf '\r\n_')" # add trailing _ to prevent trailing newline trim
crlf="${crlf%_}" # remove trailing _
http_delim="$crlf$crlf" # RFC7230 section 3

full_http_response="$(curl --silent --include --url "$endpoint")"
http_headers="${full_http_response%$http_delim*}"
http_body="${full_http_response#*$http_delim}"

case $http_headers in
  'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'*'Content-Type: application/json'*)
    # Yes, response body is JSON, so process it with jq.
    jq -n "$http_body"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

> The following works:
> echo $x | jq . 2>/dev/null  || echo $x

Except for the use of `echo` here, this is actually a good approach - it has the advantages of both simplicity and efficiency.  It is better than using the -e option naively as the return codes produced by -e are more complex.

In other words, there is much to be said for:

```
printf "%s" "$x" | jq . 2> /dev/null || printf "%s\n" "$x"
```

#### Efficiency

The argument for efficiency is as follows:

- If $x holds valid JSON, then there is no overhead.
- If $x is invalid as JSON, jq will quickly fail; in this case also, the overhead of calling jq will almost surely be no worse or not much worse than checking the `Content-Type`.

#### Warning

The official documentation for the return codes produced by jq when invoked without the `-e` option is not strictly correct, as illustrated by:

```
$ jq empty <<< 'foo bat' 2> /dev/null ; echo $?
4
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
response=$( curl -Ls -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' $endpoint )

if [ -n "$response" ]; then  # nonempty
    echo "Got server response"

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954692/check-if-string-is-a-valid-json-with-jq
    if jq --exit-status type >/dev/null 2>&1 <<<"$response"; then
        # Parsed JSON successfully and got something other than false/null
        echo "$response" | jq .
        echo "... after $i seconds"
        return 0
    else
        echo "Response is not valid JSON"
        echo "$response"
        return 1
    fi
fi
```

Comment: This is not quite right -- see the details in the jq manual about the return codes when the -e option is specified. Also calling jq twice when the input is valid seems rather wasteful.